# recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, dovecot

We are able to sent/receive mail to all domains but can't receive mail from Gmail. We are used **postfix, dovecot** on centos 6 servers.These are the mail error logs on the centos 6

```
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: connect from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52]
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52]
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/cleanup[25023]: 8CBDA80058: message-id=<20190502055112.8CBDA80058@mail.portperrylamaze.com>
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/qmgr[25000]: 8CBDA80058: from=<double-bounce@mail.portperrylamaze.com>, size=953, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: disconnect from mail-wm1-f52.google.com[209.85.128.52]
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/cleanup[25023]: D2A6780074: message-id=<20190502055112.8CBDA80058@mail.portperrylamaze.com>
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/qmgr[25000]: D2A6780074: from=<double-bounce@mail.portperrylamaze.com>, size=1108, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/local[25028]: 8CBDA80058: to=<postmaster@mail.portperrylamaze.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.33, delays=0.28/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as D2A6780074)
May  2 05:51:12 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/qmgr[25000]: 8CBDA80058: removed
May  2 05:51:13 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/pipe[25033]: D2A6780074: to=<postmaster@portperrylamaze.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.27, delays=0.04/0/0/0.23, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
May  2 05:51:13 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/qmgr[25000]: D2A6780074: removed
May  2 05:51:17 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: connect from unknown[141.98.80.33]
May  2 05:51:17 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: connect from unknown[141.98.80.33]
May  2 05:51:20 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: warning: unknown[141.98.80.33]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
May  2 05:51:20 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[141.98.80.33]
May  2 05:51:20 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: disconnect from unknown[141.98.80.33]
May  2 05:51:20 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25021]: connect from unknown[141.98.80.33]
May  2 05:51:24 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25086]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem: disabling TLS support
May  2 05:51:24 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25086]: warning: TLS library problem: 25086:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('</etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
May  2 05:51:24 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25086]: warning: TLS library problem: 25086:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
May  2 05:51:24 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25086]: warning: TLS library problem: 25086:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
May  2 05:51:24 ip-172-31-14-2 postfix/smtpd[25086]: connect from unknown[165.227.46.130]
```

Comment: `can't` is an insufficient problem description. What exactly are you trying to do, what error messages are logged?

Comment: When I sent mail from Gmail to domain mail id getting above error logs in the mail log. I have added mail error logs on the above. Please see & tell some solution to me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your TLS settings are not complete, most mail servers will probably fall back to insecure plain text SMTP but it's possible that Gmail refuses to work with unencrypted connections. Sadly, the answer in the linked article isn't really helpful.

Some steps that you should do:

- Configure a real domain name for the server, including proper reverse DNS
- Get and install a TLS certificate for the domain (letsencrypt certs are free, there is no good reason not to do it)

It is very likely that the Gmail problem goes away with a proper TLS setup, and you'll have a safer server.

By the way, in the log, you can also see a brute force connection attempt. Please make sure that all accounts on your server have strong passwords, or your server will become a spam emitter in no time.